# MariaDB 10: CHECK TABLE does not return

Tags: mariadb

**Problem / Observation**: When executing `CHECK TABLE MYDB.ICONS;` in `mysql`, the call does not return (within an hour). The same is with `SELECT ID FROM MYDB.ICONS;` and all other statements at this table.

**Environment**:

- Server version: 10.5.9-MariaDB-1:10.5.9+maria~focal mariadb.org binary distribution
- The MariaDB server runs within a docker container.
- In that database table are about 200 small SVG files plus meta information. So it's maybe about 0,5 MB volume.

**Other pieces of the puzzle**:

- I've got a similar database where executing `CHECK TABLE MYDB.ICONS;` in `mysql` takes 0.008 seconds.
- The last statement at the database was `ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS MYDB.ICONS ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS AUTHOR_TYPE TINYTEXT`

**Questions**:

1. How can I encourage `CHECK TABLE` to return?
2. How can I encourage `SELECT` statements at that table to return?
3. What are the recommended next steps in this situation? What should I investigate / try?

Comment: How big is the container?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: @RickJames the database is about 18 GB. And `SHOW VARIABLES where variable_name = 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';` delivered `innodb_buffer_pool_size` = 134217728.

Comment: `CHECK TABLE` has virtually no use on MySQL.  Why are you using it?

Comment: `SELECT` statements did not return at that table. My hope was that `CHECK TABLE` could give me a hint to the cause.

Comment: What ENGINE is used for that table?  Please provide (if possible) `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'ICONS';`

Comment: @RickJames : Your `show table status` statement shows that Engine is InnoDB. In the meantime I dropped the corrupted table and recreated it (see answer below). So the problem doesn't exist any more. Thanks anyway! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately it was just the ICONS table which was easy to recreate in my case.

So I dropped the table (attention: this will delete the data) with `DROP TABLE MYDB.ICONS;` and recreated the table and the content/data.